# How to make event trigger at the same time on all devices regardless of timezone

Tags: java, android, calendar, timezone

If my application triggers an event at 9pm EST, It should also trigger this event at 6pm PST.

Currently I am parsing a feed and this feed says that the event will run at `9` pm EST.  Without altering the feed, what is the best way to make my code universal to anyone that opens the application in any timezone.

Comment: 9PM EST is a specific moment in time, no matter in which time zone you are. For a person opening the app in PST the event will happen at 6pm. Can you please explain in more detail, what is exactly the problem here?

Comment: As a rule of thumb, you should use the [UTC timezone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) internally everywhere in your code. Only for presentation or when accepting user input should you convert to/from other timezones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *always* store dates as a UTC time (with a time zone stored separately). Then all alarm devices can easily convert that into their own local time, and make the alarm at the appropriate time.

Alarms that should be at 9am no matter what time zone then is stored without a time zone.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the device's current time zone like so:

```
TimeZone.getDefault()
```

....and then convert the current time of device and the time of feed to GMT.

Now you must test if they are equal.

Answer (score 0):

use TimeToNow by using prettytime  http://www.ocpsoft.org/prettytime/

it will give you the result as 4 hour ago or moment ago which will remove the time zone factors